# Problems in something vs Problems with something?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

May I know what is the difference between problems **in** doing something and problems **with** doing something?

Comment: There is no difference that I can think of.

Comment: For me problems with doing something are the bad results, but problems in doing something are the difficulties.